# C++ extraction operator : how can one know the number of digits read?

Tags: c++, extraction-operator

I read an integer number :

```
is >> myInteger;
```

Now I want to know how many digits were read (I'm talking of the possible leading zeros). How can I do that?

Comment: Looks like an XY problem. Why do you need it?

Comment: imo the easiest (and logical) way would be to read it into a string instead because when you read it into an int, *information that you need is discarded* by the conversion automatically, and so if you do choose to read into an int anyways your only solutions would be hacks.

Comment: The original problem consists in reading a double, without loss of precision.
The double is read as an integer (integer part) + a char (.) + another integer (fractional part). The question refers to the reading of this last integer.

Comment: This will not work, try reading 3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974944592307816406286.

Comment: The double I'm trying to read has at most 9 digits to the right of the decimal separator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can:

- get the value as a string, then parse it separately, however you wish (check length, count zeros, etc).
- use is.tellg for this; Keep in mind that tellg will give you buffer positions, not not what was at those positions (it could be space characters or zeros)
- read the buffer character by character using is.get, then process values according to your needs.

Comment: Formally, `tellg` can also return a structured result, which isn't even directly convertible into an integral type.

Answer (score 2):

You could get the value of [is.tellg()](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/tellg/) before you stream in the integer, then get it again and find the difference.

**EDIT**: Although as pointed out in the comments that will just tell you how many elements of the stream were consumed, some of which may be whitespace.

Comment: Note: this does not disregard leading whitespace skipped during the extraction.

Comment: @DanielEarwicker its a straight forward approach if there is none, however. If that can be guaranteed (such as a pull loop until non-whitespace followed by an `unget()`, or `peek()` + `get()` looping, then the extraction), certainly this would clearly work.